# How to build Qtkeychain with Windows?

Tags: owncloud

I'm trying to build my OwnCloud client. I'm using "Generic Build Instructions" from this link - https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.5/building.html.

I'm stuck at 3 step with an error:

> Could NOT find Qt5Keychain (missing: QTKEYCHAIN_LIBRARY)

I downloaded Qtkeychain and compiled it using this link - https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain/wiki.

Everything is in my C disk. PATHS are set correctly. Can someone tell me what am missing here.

Adding PATH photo:

[image]

Adding a photo to be clear what am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Same problem. Should we open an issue at https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues?

https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain contains only the files needed for -DQTKEYCHAIN_INCLUDE_DIR.

There are different instructions out there how to compile qtkeychain, but - and this is the main problem - none of them result in the creation of a lib file, which would be needed for -DQTKEYCHAIN_LIBRARY:

https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain/wiki, 
Compilation on Windows

https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/master/doc/building.rst, Windows Development Build, Step 5

Answer (score -1):

How did you compile qtkeychain?

With the environment variable %QTDIR% set correctly, e.g. C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015, you should be able to compile qtkeychain

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .
mingw32-make
```

and get a 32bit file named "libqt5keychain.dll.a".

You can then add the directory containing this file to your Windows path environment variable. This should work (it does for Nextcloud, at least).

Comment: How does this statement answer the question?  Shouldn't this be a comment and not an answer?

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I just updated my "answer", adding more information and details about what I've tried so far (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, Have the same problem?). Should I still move it to a comment?

Comment: No, the "answer" is exactly that - for answers.  If you have a question, it should be posted as a question, not an answer.  If you have a comment, it should be posted as a comment.  I would recommend self-deleting this yourself before the moderators get to it.

Comment: It is possible to participate in an answering process by providing more data on the question. It would however need to be information more or less "created" by you. Long experiments, complex analysis, that would most likely by an appreciated participation. It is a question of taste/opinion, what makes such a participation an answer. I feel this one is not yet beyond the border of a comment. So please yes, do change this into a (probably valuable) comment. (Downvote not by me.)